# Is there a way to "uncheckout" a branch from a worktree

Tags: git

How can I make git forget that a worktree once contained a branch, say integration-branch.

I have a worktree some-stuff that was based on integration-branch and I did a git squash merge on that branch, which means was reset to actually be integration-branch.  However, I deleted the directory (see below).   But, whenever I make a new worktree say other-stuff based upon integration-branch and try to do a squash merge, it makes me recreate the worktree directory some-stuff and do the integration there.

I want it instead to checkout integration-branch to the current worktree (other-stuff) and do the squash here and after I have done the push allow me to forget that this worktree (other-stuff, some-stuff) ever existed and ever contained the branch integration-branch.

It won't even let me make a new worktree for "integration-branch" claiming that it is already checked out to "some-stuff" even if the worktree for some-stuff has been deleted with `rm -rf some-stuff`.

How do I make git forget that some-stuff ever existed?  Somewhere, it is tenaciously holding onto that worktree.

I first tried `git worktree rm some-stuff`.
I later tried `git checkout dummy` and `git branch dummy` in the somestuff worktree.
I have also deleted (`rm -rf some-stuff`).

Comment: I think people are producing confused answers as they start with the assumption that you have only the one standard work-tree, instead of starting from the assumption that you ran `git worktree add`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap a bit, you started with:

```
git worktree add ../integration-branch
```

(or something similar) to create a *second* work-tree somewhere outside the standard work-tree area.  That second work-tree existed, and had branch `integration-branch` checked out.

If you have, since then, *removed* the second work-tree entirely, simply run:

```
git worktree prune
```

in the main work-tree to get Git to *notice* that the additional work-tree no longer exists, and remove it from the list of other work-trees and their checked-out branches.  Note that this will inspect *all* added work-trees to see if they still exist: if you added five work-trees, all on their own branches, so that six branches are currently considered checked-out, and subsequently removed two of them, the `prune` will leave you with four checked-out branches.

If you haven't removed the other work-tree, you can move into it and change its `HEAD` to some other branch, or to no branch at all:

```
(cd ../integration-branch; git checkout --detach integration-branch)
```

for instance.  (The parentheses here are for `bash` or any other POSIX-ish shell, to make the parenthesized sub-commands run in a sub-shell so that your main shell remains in the current top-level directory of the main work-tree.)

Comment: Close, both worktrees were in the standard work-tree area.  However, the prune command sounds like what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but: it's not a great idea to put an added work-tree underneath a regular one.  Too easy to accidentally add the added work-tree's files to the main repository....

Comment: I always put the worktrees side-by-side in the area that git has created for them and I never use the main repository.  The actual pathnames look something more like this:

/repos/myname/branch

Comment: So there would have been /repos/myname/some-stuff and /repos/myname/other-stuff.  The branch names omitted all that though and were integration-branch, some-sfuff, and other-stuff.  We don't squash merge into master, we only squash  into integration-branch and we use a pull from integration-branch when we create a new working branch.

Answer (score 1):

So if you merged your integration branch you still have the local and probably also the remote branch there. To get rid of them you have to delete them.

```
git branch -D integration                # Delete local branch
git push origin --delete integration     # Delete remote branch
```

No this branch does not exitst anymore and you can create it again with `git checkout -b integration` based on the current worktree.

Another option if you want to directly reuse your integration branch and you already merged it into master is the following

```
git checkout integration               # No you are back at you unmerged changes
git reset --hard origin/master         # Now your integration branch has you latest changes on master, so also the merege
git push origin --force integration    # Update the remote integration branch to the new changes
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the integration branch it is a branch shared by the team (effectively a sub-master).  I just don't want it checked out anywhere.  I will try branch -D some-sfuff and see if that helps,

Comment: I will try branch -D some-sfuff and see if that helps,   It didn't.  It also wouldn't let me git branch -D intergration, saying it was already checkout out to some-stuff.  Nor, in the some-stuff directory would it let me do a get checkout integration (claiming it was already checked out).

Answer (score 0):

Do you think filtering the branch against unwanted directory would be an option for you?
[Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

I admit that I am not entirely sure if I got your point. My understanding was that you don't want git to keep track of the folder even if it was already added / removed in the past.
Then you could also add it to .gitignore if you think this could be an option

Comment: Thanks its not a folder I want to ignore.  It's a worktree, which is kind of like a sub-repo.

Comment: then how about prunning the worktree: "git worktree prune"

Answer (score 0):

I found under the root .git directory a worktrees sub-directory and in that sub-directories for some-stuff and other-stuff.  Deleting those caused git to forget out those working trees.  Apparently, they were not getting removed by the "git worktree rm" command.

I must admit the deleting stuff in the .git directory is not something I like doing, but one of my colleagues suggested looking there.