# git repo overgrown with unwanted files in source directory

Tags: git

I have a repo into which I inadvertently put a number of large files into the source directory and didn't notice the error until I checked out to another location. It is huge. It used to download in two seconds and now takes three minutes.

I have removed directories but don't see how to filter out files of a specific type -- by extension or name pattern.

Is there a standard way to do this? Or a hack?

Comment: This is about private data, but it's the same principle. https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that even though you removed the files in your last commit, the files still exist in the repository under the commit when they were added.

### BFG

The easiest option to remove the files completely from your Git repository is to use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) ([Reference](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)).

```
bfg --delete-files name_of_file.txt
```

### Git Filter-Branch

The other option is to use `git filter-branch` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17824718/250168)). The following example completely removes the `./text_files` directory from a Git repository.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf text_files" --prune-empty HEAD
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

### Afterwards

After you remove the files, you may want to configure Git to ignore them.

```
echo text_files/ >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Ignore text_files directory'
```

You will also need to override your remote repository.

```
git push origin master --force
```

**Note:** If anyone else has cloned this Git repository, they will need to reset their local copy to point to the new HEAD.

Comment: I had alredy removed some unwanted directories using filter-tree. That was not a problem . However I had large files in the `source` directory so I could not remove the directories in that way. However I have at EncryptedWatermelon's suggestiiong run  bfg. But since you've put it as an answer I'll give you the tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard to do all files with an extension. For instance,

```
git rm *.txt
```

would remove all files with the .txt extension. The wildcard can replace any text so you might be able to use it for the name pattern too.

Comment: Thank you but I believe this will remove only from the current commit. I want to remove all target files from the history. I will try the suggestion from @EncryptedWatermelon