# .vs-code server/bin and tabnine extension trying to push to GitHub, failing

Tags: reactjs, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

I'm trying to push my code to GitHub, but keep getting the following errors:

```
remote: warning: File .vscode-server/bin/e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662/node is 75.64 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 0d8800fdb9c63ca4691425c2af625642fe616e4fc3de1320cdb47e20a5fc07bf
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File .local/share/TabNine/models/ce94127b.tabninemodel is 241.05 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/elilogbro/p-rails.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/elilogbro/p-rails.git'
```

I don't think the Tabnine extension nor the .vscode-sever file should be getting to pushed to GitHub and I've never encountered these errors on other projects I've done. Should I somehow add these files to .gitignore, or is there another way to prevent them from being included in the push?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think the Tabnine extension nor the .vscode-sever file should be getting to pushed to GitHub

Then use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) (Python-based, must be [installed](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) first) to [remove from your local repository history those folders (and their content)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544937/6309).

Only once those folder and large content are no longer part of your local repository commits would you be able to push.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of dealing with this issue, I found out that I had accidentally `git init` a level above my repo, so my entire directory was trying to push to GitHub. To fix the issue, in my directory i `git remote remove origin`, then cd'd into my project folder, `git init, git add ., git commit -m, and git push -u origin main`.