# Almost empty git repo has huge size

Tags: git, bitbucket, size, push, limit

I had an iOS repo on bitbucket and reached a limit of 4Gb. The repo started to deny any commits.

I decided to remove Pods folder using one of these instructions:

[Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

https://stellarflavor.com/2021/12/25/how-to-remove-pushed-pods-folder-from-git-repository/

The repo denied "force push" even if it reduces the repo size so I decided to drop all existing commits to the initial one which contains one small file (`.gitignore`).

The problem is I reduced repo size to acceptable limit but the `.git` folder is still huge (more than 99% of whole repo size even when git history is fully dropped). Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you call garbage collection since you cleaned history? (`git gc [--aggressive]`, doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))

Comment: GC is only on a local directory, not on any remote, so running `git gc` on your system won't affect Bitbucket's copy. If Bitbucket is rejecting new pushes because their copy of the repo is too large, then you need to talk to them.

Comment: You need to shrink the size of the remote repository. A remote repository has refs invisible to the users. They refer to git data and therefore the data can't be cleaned up. A hosting service is expected to provide a housekeeping task that helps the user to clean up the repository hosted in their server. A workaround is to create a new repository and push the new branches to it.

Comment: @JimRedmond I found out how to solve it. I got an error on `push` so I cloned this repo into another folder and performed some "force push" commands to clean everything but initial commit. Then I switched back to the local repo with deleted Pods folder and performed "force push" again. Currently it works but this "git garbage" still wastes free local and remote disk space.

Comment: @ElpieKay if I had created a new repo It means dropping project commit history. It is possible but is worse than the current solution with "garbage" persisting inside repo

Comment: @Gargo You don't have to drop commit history. Rewrite the history and push the rewritten history to the new repo. The new history refers to much less data.

Comment: @ElpieKay you missed one thing - both local and remote repo contain huge `.git` folder so I can't just push this local repo with fixed history to another place.