# How to rewrite history so that all changes made within a folder are removed?

Tags: git

This question is about rewriting git history.  Six months ago I decided to make changes over an existing subfolder of my repository, and now I've changed my mind and want to undo that and all the associated history.  Note, I want changes outside that subfolder should be left as is.

So, specifically, I am trying to remove the history of all the changes made within one of the subfolders of the repo, from a certain date onwards.

The end result I am hoping for should look like no edits/adds/deletes were ever made in the subfolder after that date.

Looking at the the answer to [Remove file from git repository (history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164581/remove-file-from-git-repository-history), and also http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository, the closest I've got is this:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch TheFolderToRemove' --prune-empty --all xxxxxx..HEAD 
git reset --hard
git remote rm origin
rm -r .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive
git prune
```

This removes all the files in the subfolder.

Can someone please show me how to modify this so that it just removes the changes applied within the folder?  Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the `filter-branch` with `git rm --cached` tells git to remove the directory and stage that removal!  It only did what you told it to do.

#### If you still have the original objects:  <sup><sub>(i.e. you didn't actually run `gc` and `prune`)</sub></sup>

You want to use `git reset` to *unstage* changes to that directory from the index, not remove the directory itself:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git reset -q xxxxxx TheFolderToRemove' \
>     --prune-empty -- --all xxxxxx..HEAD
```

where `xxxxxx` is the commit with state you want the folder to be in.

#### If you do not still have the original objects: <sup><sub>(i.e. you pruned the old tree from your repository)</sub></sup>

Checkout the commit in which the folder is shown as removed (I believe it should be the commit after `xxxxxx`), undo the removal, amend the commit, and rebase the rest of history on top:

```
$ git checkout -b temp <commit_after_xxxxxx>
$ git checkout HEAD^ <removed_folder>
$ git commit --amend
[temp abcdef1] <message>
```

Then, if `master` is your only branch:

```
$ git rebase --preserve-merges temp master
```

Comment: Trying this, I find that the `git reset` fails if the path is not in the commit.  I couldn't find an ignore unmatched option for reset, so I tried modifying this to the following: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'if [ -d TheFolderToRemove ]; then git reset TheFolderToRemove; fi' --prune-empty --all xxxxxx..HEAD`.  This runs without error, but no changes are made.  Any ideas on how to avoid the reset error?

Comment: Try `git reset xxxxxx TheFolderToRemove`, where `xxxxxx` is the sha1 of the commit that has that folder in the state you want it.  I tried it with a folder that isn't in the current commit and it worked for me.  (I edited the answer.)

Comment: What you had didn't make any changes because it was examining the working tree to see if TheFolderToRemove existed, not the index.  If my last comment didn't work, try `if git ls-files --error-unmatch TheFolderToRemove &> /dev/null; then git reset ...`.

Comment: BTW I needed another `--` before the `--all` otherwise it's a syntax error.  However, the specific commit form of reset isn't working for me: I get an error on the first rewrite, listing out the unstaged changes after the reset, and then `index filter failed`.

Comment: Later - adding `-q` fixed it, ie `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git reset -q xxxxxx TheFolderToRemove' --prune-empty -- --all xxxxxx..HEAD`.  Please edit your answer so I can accept it - thx.

Answer (score 0):

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatched somefolder/somefolder' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

The -rf parameter removes all files in that folder or subfolder recursively.