# Remove file from history completely

Tags: git

A colleague has done a few things I told them not to do:

- forked the origin repo online
- cloned the fork, added a file that shouldn't have been added to that local repo
- pushed this to their fork

I've then:

- merged the changes from the fork and found the file

I want to remove this from:

- my local repo
- the fork
- their local repo

I have a solution for removing something from the history, taken from [Remove file from git repository (history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164581/remove-file-from-git-repository-history). What I need to know is, should my colleague also go through this, and will a subsequent push remove all info from the fork? (I'd like an alternative to just destroying the fork, as I'm not sure my colleague will do this)

```
SOLUTION: This is the shortest way to get rid of the files:

check .git/packed-refs - my problem was that I had there a refs/remotes/origin/master line for a remote repository, delete it, otherwise git won't remove those files
(optional) git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/#{pack-name}.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -5 - to check for the largest files
(optional) git rev-list --objects --all | grep a0d770a97ff0fac0be1d777b32cc67fe69eb9a98 - to check what files those are
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file_names' - to remove the file from all revisions
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ - to remove git's backup
git reflog expire --all --expire='0 days' - to expire all the loose objects
(optional) git fsck --full --unreachable - to check if there are any loose objects
git repack -A -d - repacking the pack
git prune - to finally remove those objects
```

Comment: Note that if you do this with a repo you've already pushed from, or that someone's pulled from, things might get weird... you'd have to do it in every copy, i'd think.

Comment: Yep, that's why I haven't just gone ahead with it, but I know no one else has touched their fork.

Comment: or will touch their fork, I should add.

Comment: Destroying the fork is really the cleanest option, i think.  I'm pretty sure that rewriting history locally won't do much good; all the warnings and such that i've seen suggest git would get pretty confused when the two repos disagree about stuff that already happened.

Comment: Good call. I'm setting out some new guidelines to try and stop this in future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pushing will definitely cause little trouble as you won't have a linear history. Using `--force` flag to push and pull should do the job.

Although, if not, ask your colleague to reset their branch at the first known commit `git reset --hard <initial commit sha-1>` and then ask them to pull. This way should work as the reset won't properly be a change in the local branch; the branch will only be marked as behind it's remote counterpart by lots of commit. Then, fetching and merging will go easy as they'll go up all the way with a linear history.

But of course, such a manoeuvre need organization/timing between your team.