# Cleaning Git Repository: Rails Project, added Gems to Repo by mistake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, resource-cleanup

I was trying to solve an issue with some gem conflicts, and I added all of my gems to vendor/cache, I have since removed them, but now I have a 40M pack file where it used to be less than 1M.

I have tried to filter the branch

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch vendor/cache' --prune-empty -- --all
```

This goes through a list of rm commands, for example:

```
rm 'vendor/cache/sass-3.2.8.gem'
```

and then at the end

```
Rewrite 9c90286ba515f46919e82e73e2c01a5db1762668 (202/202)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

Finally I run

```
git gc --aggressive --expire=now
```

But I still have the same huge number of objects, and the pack file is still 40M. I even try forcing a push when this was complete with no change. Any idea how I can clean up my repository following this mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the answer at the bottom of the question or in the accepted answer here:
[Remove file from git repository (history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164581/remove-file-from-git-repository-history)

The key is in that warning line you have:

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

The solution discusses how to get rid of that so that the other steps accomplish what you want and reduce the size back down.