# git-gui reports it has 256 loose objects each time is run and suggests compression which goes fine. How to fix it?

Tags: git

After an unexpected shutdown, now git seemingly works fine but each time is run is asking for compression since it finds 256 loose objects. Is it possible to be cleaned?

Comment: Have you tried running `git gc`? (And you're not talking about the 256 duplicate objects that in some repos always appear while running `gc`, are you? I think that's just an artifact of the way it performs the compression.)

Comment: Have you tried `git fsck`? Also you can clone your repo to get a clean .git directory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run `git gc`. If that doesn't work, please copy the error message.

Comment: Thanks; that fixed it. I guess the unexpected shutdown left some unnecessary files around that confused the default system startup.

Comment: After `git gc` also run `git prune`.

Comment: What does these commands do? Are we supposed to (1) run them blindly or (2) Google it before doing it? :) Could you please include a very short explanation as to why run `git gc` (and/or what does it do) and should we run `git prune` too and why? Thanks folks! (EDIT: Or at least link them :p)

Comment: See some explanation here: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-gc-and-pruning-this.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, git gc did not solve it for me (even with the most aggressive etc. options).
But it worked:

```
git config --global gui.gcwarning false
```

(it suppresses the window pop-up that is really annoying)
See [How to skip "Loose Object" popup when running 'git gui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui)

Comment: Ouch! "There is no problem if I can't see it!". Although I do understand it can be quite annoying if you didn't manage to fix and your git works fine anyway.

Comment: Running `git gc` then `git prune` solves it, as I have learned-experienced meanwhile. See also http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-gc-and-pruning-this.html