# Git Gui: Perpetually getting "This repository currently has approximately 320 loose objects."

Tags: git, git-gui

Every time I start Git Gui on a particular project I get this message:

> This repository currently has approximately 320 loose objects.

[image]

I then proceed to click *Yes*, and I get this dialog:

[image]

The thing is, when I open Git Gui again, **I get the exact same message**, again about 320 loose objects! It's as if clicking *Yes* had no effect at all.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git count-objects -v` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip "Loose Object" popup when running 'git gui'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thanks, I found the answer there. Running `git gc` explicitly from the command line worked for me, as per [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui#comment921715_1106656).

Comment: Related, for when even there are unlinking errors while compressing the object database: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11774397/1959808

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just simply skipping the pop up, as [How to skip "Loose Object" popup when running 'git gui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui) suggests in the accepted answer is overlooking the fact that Git is communicating a possible performance issue to you. This should be fixable by running this command from the command line:

```
cd path/to/your/git/repo
git gc --aggressive
```

From the output of `git help gc`:

> Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been created from prior invocations of git add.
>
> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.
>
> --aggressive
>
> > Usually git gc runs very quickly while providing good disk space utilization and performance. This option will cause git gc to more aggressively optimize the repository at the expense of taking much more time. The effects of this optimization are persistent, so this option only needs to be used occasionally; every few hundred changesets or so.

This should keep the prompt from popping up for a while.

Comment: What is strange is that simply running `git gc` from the command line fixed it for me. May be `git gui` runs something like `git gc --extra-unaggressive` :)

Comment: It seems that git gui calls `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" "C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-repack" -a -d -l`

Comment: `git prune` seems to fix it when `git gc` doesn't.

Comment: @Mahn That just worked for me too. (Git 1.7.1)  Supposedly `git gc` should call `git prune`, but running it manually it what finally fixed this for me.

Comment: You generally don't want to run with `--aggressive`; that causes `git` to recalculate deltas which is usually unproductive and very time-consuming; see [this post](https://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/)--the `man` page is misleading. Probably just plain `git gc` is enough in this case.

Comment: Had to use `--prune=all` to get rid of the message. Neither `git gc` on the command line nor the options `--aggressive` or `--prune` did the trick.

Comment: @JeffClites The article you refer to is (as of this date) 11 years old, and states "For this reason --aggressive will probably be removed from the manpages and left as an undocumented feature for a while.". Without digging further, it seems weird that the broken message is still there. Is there a chance that the behavior has been modified sine the article was written?

Comment: @daw --prune=all is not recognized

Comment: The fact that clicking "Yes" on git gui's popup does not actually address the problem seems like a bug. Is there a place to enter bug reports for git gui?

Answer (score 13):

I use command:

> git gc --prune=now

and no more too many loose object warning after done.

source of reference:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: Have to say that this was the solution that worked for me. Strangely, `git gc --aggressive` did not remove the warning (and neither did clicking on the UI, which seems to perform a simple `git gc`).