# Do I ever need to run git gc on a bare repo?

Tags: git, git-gc

[`man git-gc`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) doesn't have an obvious answer in it, and I haven't had any luck with Google either (although I might have just been using the wrong search terms).

I understand that you should occasionally run `git gc` on a local repository to prune dangling objects and compress history, among other things -- but is a shared bare repository susceptible to these same issues?

If it matters, our workflow is multiple developers pulling from and pushing to a bare repository on a shared network drive. The "central" repository was created with `git init --bare --shared`.

Comment: Note: setting **`gc.autodetach`** (Git 2.0 Q2 2014) can help running `git gc --auto` without bloking the user. see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22358178/6309).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) commented on [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532740/do-i-ever-need-to-run-git-gc-on-a-bare-repo/3533073#3533073), `git gc` *should* be called automatically called during "normal" use of a bare repository.

I just ran `git gc --aggressive` on two bare, shared repositories that have been actively used; one with about 38 commits the past 3-4 weeks, and the other with about 488 commits over roughly 3 months.  Nobody has manually run `git gc` on either repository.

#### Smaller repository

```
$ git count-objects
333 objects, 595 kilobytes

$ git count-objects -v
count: 333
size: 595
in-pack: 0
packs: 0
size-pack: 0
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0

$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 325, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (323/323), done.
Writing objects: 100% (325/325), done.
Total 325 (delta 209), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.

$ git count-objects -v
count: 8
size: 6
in-pack: 325
packs: 1
size-pack: 324
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0

$ git count-objects
8 objects, 6 kilobytes
```

#### Larger repository

```
$ git count-objects
4315 objects, 11483 kilobytes

$ git count-objects -v
count: 4315
size: 11483
in-pack: 9778
packs: 20
size-pack: 15726
prune-packable: 1395
garbage: 0

$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 8548, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8468/8468), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8548/8548), done.
Total 8548 (delta 7007), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.

$ git count-objects -v
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 8548
packs: 1
size-pack: 8937
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0

$ git count-objects
0 objects, 0 kilobytes
```

I wish I had thought of it before I `gc`ed these two repositories, but I should have run `git gc` *without* the `--aggressive` option to see the difference.  Luckily I have a medium-sized active repository left to test (164 commits over nearly 2 months).

```
$ git count-objects -v
count: 1279
size: 1574
in-pack: 2078
packs: 6
size-pack: 2080
prune-packable: 607
garbage: 0

$ git gc
Counting objects: 1772, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1073/1073), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1772/1772), done.
Total 1772 (delta 1210), reused 1050 (delta 669)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.

$ git count-objects -v
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 1772
packs: 1
size-pack: 1092
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0

$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 1772, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1742/1742), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1772/1772), done.
Total 1772 (delta 1249), reused 0 (delta 0)

$ git count-objects -v
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 1772
packs: 1
size-pack: 1058
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
```

Running `git gc` clearly made a large dent in `count-objects`, even though we regularly `push` to and `fetch` from this repository.  But upon reading [the manpage for `git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), I noticed that the default loose object limit is 6700, which we apparently had not yet reached.

So it appears that the conclusion is **no**, you don't *need* to run `git gc` manually on a bare repo;<sup>*</sup> but with the default setting for `gc.auto`, it might be a long time before garbage collection occurs automatically.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> *Generally*, you shouldn't need to run `git gc`.  But sometimes [you might be strapped for space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212008/forcing-remote-repo-to-compress-gc-with-git) and you should run `git gc` manually or set `gc.auto` to a lower value.  My case for the question was simple curiosity, though.</sub>

Comment: `git gc --help` also mentions option `--no-prune` and `git prune` which might come handy in bare repos, depending on the usage type

Answer (score 17):

From the `git-gc` man page:

> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within **each
>   repository** to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating
>   performance.

Emphasis mine. Bare repositories are repositories too!

Further explanation: one of the housekeeping tasks that `git-gc` performs is *packing* and *repacking* of loose objects. Even if you never have any *dangling* objects in your bare repository, you will -- over time -- accumulate lots of loose objects. These loose objects should periodically get packed, for efficiency. Similarly, if a large number of packs accumulate, they should periodically get repacked into larger (fewer) packs.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clarifying one of the reasons that gc might be necessary on a bare repo.

Comment: It's definitely true that `gc` needs to be run on all repos, bare or not. It's also true that enough commands run it automatically that you essentially never have to. In the case of a bare repo, it's `receive-pack` that invokes `gc --auto`. (Sometimes you may want to manually run `git gc --aggressive`, which will "more aggressively optimize the repository at the expense of taking much more time", but you may not find that to be important.)

Comment: @Jefromi: I agree. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be very well documented which commands run `git gc --auto`. I checked the `git-receive-pack` man page before writing my answer, and there's no mention of it there. So for the average user, I think it's difficult to know if `git gc` needs to be manually run. The fact that the `git gc` man page still recommends that user's *do* run it manually seems to only add more confusion! Perhaps this is something that should be mentioned on the mailing list.

Comment: Yeah, git's documentation unfortunately can be a bit spotty sometimes. Maybe if I get ambitious I'll submit a patch. From a quick survey of the source: `merge`, `receive-pack`, `am`, `rebase --interactive`, and `svn` call `gc --auto` directly. That's not a complete list, though, since other commands may call those.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `git gc --auto` is that it can be blocking.

But with the new (Git 2.0 Q2 2014) setting **`gc.autodetach`**, you now can do it without any interruption:

See [commit 4c4ac4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c4ac4db2c933fbae1c6e6bcf90d9bee5f823fc7) and [commit 9f673f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f673f9477c63433aa0774c11b9e42979721f4d6) ([Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy, aka pclouds](https://github.com/pclouds)):

> `gc --auto` takes time and can block the user temporarily (but not any less annoyingly).
>   Make it run in background on systems that support it.
>   The only thing lost with running in background is printouts. But `gc output` is not really interesting.
>   You can keep it in foreground by changing `gc.autodetach`.

---

Note: only git 2.7 (Q4 2015) will make sure to **not loose the error message**.
See [commit 329e6e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/329e6e8794c347d3da92144f88ad838945508ac6) (19 Sep 2015) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 076c827](https://github.com/git/git/commit/076c8278583b70547c1c5a65941a661f08210252), 15 Oct 2015)</sup>

> ### `gc`: save log from daemonized `gc --auto` and print it next time
>
> While [commit 9f673f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f673f9477c63433aa0774c11b9e42979721f4d6) (`gc`: config option for running `--auto` in background - 2014-02-08) helps reduce some complaints about '`gc --auto`' hogging the terminal, it creates another set of problems.
>
> The latest in this set is, as the result of daemonizing, `stderr` is closed and all warnings are lost. This warning at the end of `cmd_gc()` is particularly important because it tells the user how to avoid "`gc --auto`" running repeatedly.
>   Because stderr is closed, the user does not know, naturally they complain about '`gc --auto`' wasting CPU.
>
> **Daemonized `gc` now saves `stderr` to `$GIT_DIR/gc.log`.
>
>   Following `gc --auto` will not run and `gc.log` printed out until the user removes `gc.log`**.

Answer (score 1):

Some operations run `git gc --auto` automatically, so there should never be the *need* to run `git gc`, git should take care of this by itself.

Contrary to what bwawok said, there actually is (or might be) a difference between your local repo and that bare one: What operations you do with it. For example dangling objects can be created by rebasing, but it may be possible that you never rebase the bare repo, so maybe you don't ever need to remove them (because there are never any). And thus you may not need to use `git gc` that often. But then again, like I said, git should take care of this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know 100% about the logic of gc.. but to reason this out:

git gc removed extra history junk, compresses extra history, etc. It does nothing with your local copies of files.

The only difference between a bare and normal repo is if you have local copies of files.

So, I think it stands to reason that YES, you should run git gc on a bare repo.

I have never personally ran it, but my repo is pretty small and is still fast.