# Deploy to Azure from Git Local System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: git, azure

I have done [this tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html#publishing-to-azure) and after many "problems", when I'm trying to deploy to Azure from my Git Local the console show me this error:

```
remote: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
```

I'm trying to deploy to a web app in Azure and other stuff seems to work fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How big is the repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185276/find-size-of-git-repo

Comment: 80K, but my problem is when my app restore some package with Nuget  and try to install :(

Comment: I've come across this problem with a free website using coreclr and npm. Between the nuget and npm package restores and the installer copying files, it ended up using more than the included 1gb. Only "solution" I found was to upgrade to a paid-for package with more than 1gb of disc space. Not really an answer, hence posted as comment.

Comment: I have done exactly the same and works like a charm... Good point ;) @Frans

Comment: Having looked at the logs, when you specify coreclr in global.json, it seems like the entire runtime is downloaded and installed. If you don't specify anything in global.json, Azure will use the pre-installed full CLR - but that requires your projects to support them, which doesn't work on Mac (I don't think). I suspect they will sort this out as we get closer to a release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frans comment solution:

> I've come across this problem with a free website using coreclr and
>   npm. Between the nuget and npm package restores and the installer
>   copying files, it ended up using more than the included 1gb. Only
>   "solution" I found was to upgrade to a paid-for package with more than
>   1gb of disc space. Not really an answer, hence posted as comment.

This works for me too ;)