# How to know remaining/used Google Cloud Source Repository storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have just started using Google Cloud Source Repository and after pushing a big project I can't seem to know how many GBs the project is taking on Google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to see this on the console, but your can run this command

```
gcloud source repos describe <repoName>
```

You have a line with the size of the repo, in byte

```
size: '86831633'
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I found an answer that seems more easier.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found an answer.

`git count-objects -vH` (see answer by @VonC)

[Found it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185276/find-size-of-git-repository)

Comment: Do you mean this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163608/6309