# How does git do GC when there is no git server?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

`git` isn't a server-client architecture, so there is no git server. 
I read somewhere that git prunes reflog (& other garbage collection) in 90 days. Now there is no server that checks for the last reflog entry & waits for 90 days to do GC. So how does it work? Who schedules background git pruning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) ends up being run automatically during the normal use of a repo.

For example, in "[Do I ever need to run `git gc` on a bare repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532740/do-i-ever-need-to-run-git-gc-on-a-bare-repo#comment3699235_3533073)", [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) mentions:

> It's also true that enough commands run it automatically that you essentially never have to.
>   In the case of a bare repo, it's `receive-pack` that invokes `gc --auto`.

So if you are doing anything with the repo (clone/push/pull), [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) will run and checks with its internal reflog if 90 days are reached or not.

It is a local operation to the repo, with a local reflog, and it doesn't need a server at all.