# Removing a commit from gitlab

Tags: git

Recently I filled my gitlab server's hard drive and I am looking to free some space, so:

Is it possible to remove files with all of their history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Comment: and for the remote optimization problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162786/how-can-i-trigger-garbage-collection-on-a-git-remote-repository

Answer (score 1):

To get free space,

```
git gc
```

is the easiest way. It removes unnecessary files in Git.

If you want to delete specific big size files from history

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm some/big/file' HEAD
```

But please refer to http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History before do it.

If you want to delete entire repository, just delete `YOUR_REPO/.git` directory.