# Git repository is too large, even after deleting all old commits

Tags: git

so I work on a branch of a master git repository, which is now 4 GB large, because I once pushed raw data by mistake.
So what I did is to use `git reset--hard@(10)` to go back 10 commits and then used `git push -f`.
Now my commit history is clean, but the repo is still 4gb large.

How can I delete the last 10 commits. To be honest I wouldn't even mind setting back my branch completely to the same state as the master is.

Comment: That will be dealt with eventually [by the garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162786/how-can-i-trigger-garbage-collection-on-a-git-remote-repository). Unless you definitely need to reclaim that storage space **right now** you probably don't need to do anything.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for your answer. Actually I would really like to get the storage right now, as I am already dealing with this issue since 2 days. I tried to run ``git gc``, still nothing

Comment: Basically `git gc` should work, but if you already pushed to a remote repository, you need to execute `git gc` on **that** repository (as it's not an operation that changes anything about what you push).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+reduce+repository+size

Comment: Hi so basically my local copy of the branch is shrinked to 170mb, but on git it says the project is still 4GB large. However, when I download it, it is only 170mb as well.... any suggestions ?

Comment: @AbuBati5a: "on git"? What do you mean? GitHub? GitLab?

Comment: GitHub runs gc on their servers periodically. Just sit back and relax. On GitLab, do Settings > General > Advanced > Housekeeping; see 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html

Answer (score 5):

Git has a `reflog` which keeps references to the commits and HEADs you have been on for some time. These entries still hold links to your commits, and so `git gc` won't delete them (yet).

You can force that to happen by running the following:

```sh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: Hi so basically my local copy of the branch is shrinked to 170mb, but on git it says the project is still 4GB large. However, when I download it, it is only 170mb as well.... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem couple of months ago. Then i found an awesome tool to clean the git repo. Its really working well.

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: Thanks, one short question. When I use the command ``$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git``. How can I referr to my branch for  ``some-big-repo.git`` ?

Comment: switch to your branch and try