# Should "git gc" be run periodically on gerrit managed git repositories?

Tags: git, gerrit, jgit

Will running cgit periodically cause any harm (since gerrit manipulates the repo with JGit)?  Does JGit perform this function automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to run git gc (or most any other cgit command) on the server while Gerrit is running.

No, jgit does not perform this automatically.  Most groups using Gerrit have a script which runs gc once a week or so.  I tried to find some more official documentation on this, but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 4):

Gerrit has a gc command of its own:

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit gc myProject yourProject
```

or

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit gc --all
```

The user doing this call has to be in the Administrator Group.

Source: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-gc.html

Answer (score 2):

JGit's gc implementation is still in review [1], should be ready soon.

[1] https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/4705/

Answer (score -3):

Jgit is eclipse plugin for Git. 
When and how often to run "git gc" is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729/how-often-should-you-use-git-gc)

Comment: Downvoted cause: if op asks about JGit, he already knows what is it, so your first sentence is meaningless. The last part is just a link so somewhere (and not even an excerpt) so it could be a comment, not answer.

Comment: JGit is not the eclipse plugin, EGit is (which happens to use JGit).  EGit is sort of irrelevant to this question.